# ladder-like C++ virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

If I have a class inheritance relation like the following

```
               a
              /  \
             b    c
              \   |
               |  d
                \/ \
                e   f
                 \ /
                  g
```

Is the following the correct definition?

```
    class A {};
    class B: public virtual A {};
    class C: public virtual A {};
    class D: public C {};
    class E: public B, public virtual D  {};
    class F: public virtual D {};
    class G: public E, public F {};
```

I made both A and D virtually inherited because I assume each joint class need to be virtual.

Also I am not sure how C++ defines the constructor order of the above case. The link
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-vi-ctor-order says

> The very first constructors to be executed are the virtual base
>   classes anywhere in the hierarchy. They are executed in the order they
>   appear in a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the graph of base
>   classes, where left to right refer to the order of appearance of base
>   class names.
>
> After all virtual base class constructors are finished, the
>   construction order is generally from base class to derived class. The
>   details are easiest to understand if you imagine that the very first
>   thing the compiler does in the derived class’s ctor is to make a
>   hidden call to the ctors of its non-virtual base classes (hint: that’s
>   the way many compilers actually do it). So if class D inherits
>   multiply from B1 and B2, the constructor for B1 executes first, then
>   the constructor for B2, then the constructor for D. This rule is
>   applied recursively; for example, if B1 inherits from B1a and B1b, and
>   B2 inherits from B2a and B2b, then the final order is B1a, B1b, B1,
>   B2a, B2b, B2, D.
>
> Note that the order B1 and then B2 (or B1a then B1b) is determined by
>   the order that the base classes appear in the declaration of the
>   class, not in the order that the initializer appears in the derived
>   class’s initialization list.

If so, is the order like?

```
  A, D, B, C, D, F, G
```

I do not expect D is constructed before C. What is the correct constructor order?

Answer (score 9):

When constructing an object of class `G`, the virtual base classes are initialized first.  This results in the constructors for `A` and `D` being called.  The constructor for `D` will construct it's base `C` object.  Then the constructors for the non-base classes of `G` will be called, which would be `E` and `F`.  The constructor for `E` will call the constructor for `B`.  This gives the final order:

```
A C D B E F G
```

Answer (score 6):

I added constructors that call `printf` to watch what happens (code available on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/uecpq6) for the curious).  The order I got, with both clang (version 6.0.0) and gcc (versions 6.4.0 and 7.3.0), is:

```
A
C
D
B
E
F
G
```

This matches what I'd expect.  `A` and `D` have to be constructed first, but you can't construct a `D` without a C (imagine a more complex example where `D`'s constructor called into `C`.  Once all `virtual` inheritance has been satisfied, the constructors are called in the same order we expect.